# Calculating column value based on previous rows history

Tags: updates, calculated-columns

Hello I have the following table:

```
USE [dm]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Demo]    Script Date: 12/12/2012 08:09:31 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Demo](
    [File] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [version] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [label] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

--option A
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Demo]
VALUES (N'123.doc', N'1', NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Demo]
VALUES (N'123.doc', N'2', NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Demo]
VALUES (N'123.doc', N'3', N'A')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Demo]
VALUES (N'123.doc', N'4', NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Demo]
VALUES (N'123.doc', N'5', N'B')
GO
```

i need to create a query or possibly new output table or view as follows (notice new column CalcVersion). Any idea how to do that without using a programming language?

```
File    version    label   CalcVersion
123.doc 1           NULL   A.1
123.doc 2           NULL   A.2
123.doc 3           A      A.3   
123.doc 4           NULL   B.1
123.doc 5           B      B.2
```

Another possible scenario is this:

```
option B
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Demo]
VALUES (N'123.doc', N'1', N'A')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Demo]
VALUES (N'123.doc', N'2', NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Demo]
VALUES (N'123.doc', N'3', NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Demo]
VALUES (N'123.doc', N'4', N'B')
```

In that case results should be:

```
File    version   label   CalcVersion
123.doc 1           A      A.1         
123.doc 2           NULL   B.1
123.doc 3           NULL   B.2
123.doc 4           B      B.3
```

Please advise.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i think I go it:

```
 UPDATE demo set ver =(
      (SELECT TOP 1 label FROM demo t WHERE t.[file] = pt.[file] 
      and cast(t.[version] as int) > cast(pt.[version] as int) 
            AND t.label is NOT NULL 
       ORDER BY pt.[version] asc)) from demo pt
where pt.label is NULL;
```

Than concatenate it with a rank as follows:

```
    select *,     ver + '.' + cast(RANK() over (partition by [file] order by version asc) as 
varchar(10)) as ver from demo where label is null;
```